# Does Zarya's primary fire (Particle Beam) have an increase hitbox with high energy?

Tags: overwatch

I'm asking because the visual shows the beam much bigger at a high energy so I'm wondering if the hitbox is bigger was well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the [source](https://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/zarya.html):

- 3: When charged up further it will increase the width of Zarya's Particle Cannon's beam (primary fire).  Please note that the increased beam actually has a larger hit area and can make hitting targets a tad easier.